# How to use SSL correctly in Meteor?

Tags: ssl, meteor, peerjs

I am using [peerjs-server](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) with self-signed certificates as follow (in the server):

```
var base = process.env.PWD;
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;


var server = PeerServer({
    port: 9000,
    path: '/',
    ssl: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(base + '/certificates/key.pem', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(base + '/certificates/cert.pem', 'utf8')
    }
});
```

And connecting to it as follow (in the client):

```
window.peer = new Peer({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000,
    path: '/',
    debug:3,
    config: {'iceServers': [
   { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
   { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
   ]}
 });
```

The above code (client) works when I don't use self-signed certificates.

The problem I am facing now is, how to link those self-signed certificates in the client when connecting to the server?

Non of the examples I found [like this one](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/496/how-to-create-a-videochat-with-webrtc-using-peerjs-and-node-js) are using Meteor and I am struggling to achieve the same with meteor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PeerJS and it seems like its not working fully anyhow.

I would rather use Galaxy, or a self hosted linux server like AWS, DigitalOcean and run meteor build to create a regular node app.

If you then set the environmnent variable of the URL to "https://myapp.com", and also add the [force-ssl](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/force-ssl) package.

This will get your Meteor app to always use a secure connection.